# Check if an input of integers (assuming they are a Binary tree) is a Valid binary search tree?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

it is just one question, and of course any available data and coding examples are more than welcome.
I am trying to input some integers ( 12345679 ) over an EditText, and pass them like if they were a Binary tree already, then checking if this **"supposed tree"** is a Binary Search Tree.

I HAVE BEEN RESEARCHING MORE THAN A WEEK, and i could not find anything  close to this for JAVA or KOTLIN...please i need your help! seriously.. any available example..pieces of work ... they are more than welcome!

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: You mean that you have a tree and need to validate if it is a BST or not?

Comment: Yes @code_mechanic ..pretty much that..... but this tree... could it be a given...array of size n.. ?

the app would be like a .... BST checker.. you input integers .. and check them if they are  a BST .. that is what i am trying to do... like if they were the tree ...already..

Thanks for writing man! :)

Comment: If you only need to check if the array is BST, just check if its sorted, sorted array can be converted to binary tree, hence there is an algorithm binary search which works on sorted array.

Comment: yes.. i got you, but  do you have / do you know of any coding example.. i mean.. this is all Uni stuff.. but when you want to apply this for ...an Android project.. it is when it gets messy.. to me at least.. but  thanks for the info @code_mechanic i appreciate it :)

Comment: It's very easy to implement you should try it yourself, you just need to compare current element in array with next element, current element should be less than (equal to if BST support duplicate elements) next element till the length of array. [For reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-array-represents-inorder-binary-search-tree-not/)

Comment: @code_mechanic   i got it man.. thanks for the hints :) i will up vote you even ahaah...have a great weekend! :)